# How do I get the connection string associated with an nHibernate GenericADOException for logging purposes?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I need to log the server name from the connection string that was in use when the nHibernate GenericADOException was thrown.

Anyone know how to do this?  I've looked high and low on the web and haven't found anything that looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the ISession.

```
ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
string connectionString = session.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: +1 (and you would probably wrap this in a `using` block, of course)